# Play Asset Delivery in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, android-asset-delivery

I have an app but it has a lot of video assets, in order to avoid not being able to upload to Google Play, I want to try to use [Play Asset Delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery), but I can't find how to use it in React Native, I just want to separate the videos individually and use in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

To access images from an install-time asset pack I followed this guide ([faltutech blog article](https://blog.faltutech.com/2023/android/02/13/play-asset-delivery-react-native/)) up to settings.gradle. Then accessed the image via:

```
<Image
  source={{ uri: "asset:/myImage.png" }} //base directory of my_asset_pack/src/main/assets
  style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
></Image>
```

I found this solution digging around [expo file system](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/). There may be a more managed way of doing this (for both expo and non-expo) but this works.

For videos I imagine the same scheme works aswell, seeing as [react-native-video](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-video) also supports the uri convention

If you are in expo you will need to generate the android files with 'expo prebuild'

Comment: first link seems dead or atleast not opening anymore. greatful if you have another link?

Comment: web archive link [link(https://web.archive.org/web/20230329202418/https://blog.faltutech.com/2023/android/02/13/play-asset-delivery-react-native/)
however expo play asset delivery is a much better solution if you get it working https://github.com/one-am-it/expo-play-asset-delivery